# FQL get like count from friends in links

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

This might sounds complicated.

I want to retrieve links from my website whereby those links are liked by users and my friends. But I want to sort result by number of my friends' like count.

I have checked in link_stat and it provides a general stat only.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had an answer for you. I don't and I'm not sure why.

I shared a bunch of links yesterday to test a Like Button I implemented on a site. I thought this would be an easy question to answer. After playing with this for about 30 mins, I've come to the conclusion that it's not.

Looking at `/me/feed` in the API explorer, my links are there with `"type": "link"`. However when I look at `me/links` or run an FQL query `SELECT link_id, owner, url FROM link WHERE owner = me() ORDER BY created_time DESC` those links aren't there. [Bug report posted](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/376990809033134)

Anyway, you should be able to start with an FQL query something like this:

```
SELECT link_id, owner, url FROM link 
   WHERE owner IN 
     (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
     AND strpos(url, 'mysite.com') >= 0
```

Pass those `link_id`s via a Multiquery to the like table. FQL doesn't have a `count` method, so you'll have to count the likes and sort your results it in your script.

Good luck.